# ReactJS Onsen - Child State refreshing when using PushPage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onsen-ui

While developing our first app using ReactJS, I have run into a state refresh issue. We have a component that reads a list of pages from an API. This result contains the page name and content. We loop through the result set, creating tappable Ons.ListItem rows for each page. The onClick triggers a function that calls pushPage and passes the specifics as props.

Everything displays correctly, but I notice that when I change the page content that the API servers, the resulting popup page does not redraw. If I back out of the pop and re-click the list item, then it shows the new content. The list item itself also properly redraws if the title attribute gets changed in the same manner.

It seems like the PushPage is getting divorced from awareness of content changes that the parent component receives, and curious if anyone has thoughts on the best way to tackle this.

**Parent List Snippet**

```
class MoreLinks extends React.Component {

  pushCustomPage(pageDetail) {

    //Path with refresh issue
    if (pageDetail.LINK_TYPE == "PAGE") {

      this.props.navigator.pushPage({
        component: CustomPage,
        props: { MoreLinksPopPage: this.MoreLinksPopPage, navigator: this.props.navigator, pageDetail: pageDetail }
      });

    }

    if (pageDetail.LINK_TYPE == "LINK" && pageDetail.LINK_URL) {
      window.open(pageDetail.LINK_URL);
    }

  }

  loadCustomPageList(done) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("AccessToken");
    const eventid = localStorage.getItem("eventID");

    const requestOptions = { token, eventid };
    axios.post(MobileAPI.GetCustomPages(), requestOptions).then(res => {
      const user = res.data;

      if (user.Success) {
        console.log(user);
        this.setState({ customPages: user.Content.Records });
      } else if (user.Error) {
        alert(user.Message);
      } else {
        alert("An unknown error has occured. Please try again.");
      }
    });
    if (done) done();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCustomPageList();

    setInterval(this.loadCustomPageList, 30000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Ons.Page        renderToolbar={(onBackButton = null) => (
        <Ons.Toolbar>

          <div className="center">More</div>
        </Ons.Toolbar>
      )}>

    <Ons.List modifier="locations">

        {this.state.customPages && this.state.customPages.map((doc, index) => (




              <Ons.ListItem tappable={true}
              modifier="chevron"
              key={doc.PAGE_ID}
              className="list-item-container"
              onClick={() => { this.pushCustomPage( this.state.customPages[index]) }}
            >
              <Ons.Row>
                <Ons.Col width="95px">
                  <div className="action-icon">
                    <Ons.Icon icon="fa-question" />
                  </div>
                </Ons.Col>
                <Ons.Col>
                  <div className="name">{doc.PAGE_NAME}</div>
                </Ons.Col>
                <Ons.Col width="40px" />
              </Ons.Row>
            </Ons.ListItem>



        ))}

          </Ons.List>

        </Ons.Page>
    );
  }
}
```

**CustomPage Component**

```
class CustomPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pageDetail: this.props.pageDetail
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Ons.Page
        id={"EventDocuments"}
        renderToolbar={(onBackButton = null) => (
          <Ons.Toolbar>
            {onBackButton ? (
              <div className="left">
                <Ons.BackButton onClick={this.props.MoreLinksPopPage} />
              </div>
            ) : null}
            <div className="center">
              {this.state.pageDetail.PAGE_NAME}
            </div>
          </Ons.Toolbar>
        )}
      >



        {this.state.pageDetail.CONTENT.map((doc, index) => (
          <ContentRow
                key={this.state.pageDetail.CONTENT[index].contentID}
                block={this.state.pageDetail.CONTENT[index]}
              />
        ))}



      </Ons.Page>
    );
  }
}
```

**ContentRow Component**

```
class ContentRow extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      block: this.props.block
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (


      <Ons.ListItem 
      key={this.state.block.docID}


    >
    {this.state.block.Title && (
      <Ons.Row>
        <Ons.Col>
          <strong>{this.state.block.Title}</strong>
        </Ons.Col>
      </Ons.Row>
    )}

    {this.state.block.Image && (
      <Ons.Row>
        <Ons.Col>
        <img alt="ContentRowImage" style={{maxWidth:'100%'}} src={this.state.block.Image} />
        </Ons.Col>
      </Ons.Row>
    )}

    {this.state.block.Description && (
      <Ons.Row>
        <Ons.Col>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:this.state.block.Description}}></div>
        </Ons.Col>
      </Ons.Row>
    )}

    </Ons.ListItem>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this in the future, I wound up implementing redux state management into the application. Referencing the redux store in the sub pages allowed for their content to refresh automatically on changes to the state.